# sqlcmd for SQL Server removes zeros to the left of the decimal point

Tags: sql-server, format, export-to-csv, sqlcmd, leading-zero

We're trying to read data from a SQL Server table for inserting it into a `.csv` using `sqlcmd` in Linux OS.

Unfortunately when we try to read the float values from table like

```
-0.373783
```

then in files we get

```
-.373783
```

but we would like to get on file **-0.373783** as on the database table.

We don't understand why sqlcmd remove leading zeros, I mean to the left of the decimal point, the same select query on SSMS return the right number representation.

We tried to use the following statement

```
SELECT CAST(floatField AS Numeric(9,6))
```

but we keep getting the number without the zeros before the decimal point.. we are going crazy!

Thanks in advance for your suggestion

Comment: _as on the database table_ Nope, no such thing here but your assumption. Any non-string value is stored as a non-readable binary value in the database. It is the tool you use to generate a viewable resultset that "formats" numbers, dates, etc. If you want a particular format, then you need to do that in code as already posted.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

The **FORMAT()** function is using .Net CLR formatting.
Combination of '0's and '#'s will give you what you are looking for.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @var DECIMAL(10,6) = -0.373783;

SELECT @var AS [Before]
    , CAST(@var AS VARCHAR(12)) AS [After]
    , FORMAT(@var,'###0.######') AS [Formatted];
```